# Cython class forward declaration from other extension

Tags: cython, cythonize

I am trying to forward declare a class from another extension. Essentially I have a file `src/myClass/myClass.pxd` (and an associated .pyx file), which contains a definition for `cdef class myClass`. Now in another file, `src/myClass/myHelper.pxd` (with associated .pyx file), I want to forward declare the `myClass` type so that I can have a field of type `myClass` in `cdef class myHelper`. I need it to be forward declared, and cannot simply `cimport` it since `myClass` refers back to `myHelper`. The problem is that when I forward declare `myClass` as `cdef class myClass`, `cythonize` complains that the class has no definition, even though it is simply in another place. Is there a way around this?

I am not sure how `cythonize` handles this internally, but if class fields are pointers, it should be fine.

src/myClass/myClass.pxd:

```
from src.myClass.myHelper cimport myHelper

cdef class myClass:
    cdef:
        myHelper helper

    # other definitions...
```

src/myClass/myHelper.pxd:

```
cdef class myClass

cdef class myHelper:
    cdef:
        myClass helper

    # other definitions, not using the actual structure of myClass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to forward declare it at all. I can get a simple example to work with a circular cimport:

```
# A.pxd
from B cimport B

cdef class A:
    cdef B binst
```

```
# B.pxd
from A cimport A

cdef class B:
    cdef A ainst
```

```
# A.pyx
cdef class A:
    pass
```

```
cdef class B:
    pass
```

This compiles and imports fine for me. I think the forward declaration is just causing more confusion than it's solving.

Comment: I see, this worked! I was thinking of it too much like C/C++ headers I guess, where you'd need to forward declare it in such a way in order for circular dependencies like this to work.

Comment: @DavidW it works with `cdef class` but not working with `cdef cppclass` since C++ has no None to assign to properties initially, how to circular import cppclass(es)?

Comment: @datdinhquoc I don't know. I suspect it doesn't work

Comment: i found it out how, forward declaration + multiple file linking